# Correct php code for echoing html with variables

Tags: php, html

I try to echo some html code with php. But it doesn't work at all. i got two variables from a session and want to loop it to show it.
`$anz` is 10 and `$fl` is the file name.

```
<div id="magazine">
        <?php
        SESSION_START();
            $fl = $_SESSION["filesx"];
            $anz = $_SESSION["anz"];
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $anz){
                echo "<div style='background-image: url($fl+$anz.jpg);'></div>"
                $i++;
            }
        ?>
</div>
```

`$fl` is the file name and i need to add `$anz` and .jpg. 
Because there are 10 files.

Comment: What output do you actually get? What values do `$fl` and `$anz` contain? What are you expecting?

Comment: Also, note that `$fl+$anz` doesn't do concatenation

Comment: Looks fine to me so you will need to post some more info RE what you expect to get vs what you got.

Comment: Pretty sure session_start(); has to be small letters.

Comment: got an empty site. if i remove the loop, the site work..

Comment: @ErikThiart I don't believe so - as I believe PHP functions for the in-built function are case-insensitive

Comment: ($fl+$anz.jpg) should be concatenate ? try ($fl.$anz.jpg) if do not work than print_r($anz) and let us know the result

Comment: Can you post your full code all of it.

Comment: ok i got: 5d46d06b09af06.77872020.pdf10jpg and i need a dot between 10 and jpg.

Answer (score -1):

got it!

```
        <?php
    SESSION_START();
        $fl = $_SESSION["filesx"];
        $anz = $_SESSION["anz"];
        $anz = $anz -1;
        $i = 0;
        $jpg = "jpg";
        echo $fl.$anz.$jpg;
        while ($i <= $anz){
            $x = $fl.$i;
            echo "<div style='background-image: url($x.$jpg);'></div>";
            $i++;
        }



    ?>
```

Thanks to all!